# fabric script / bash: how to detect git file changed

Tags: git, bash, symfony, grep, fabric

I'm creating a `fabric` deploy script for my `Symfony` project.
I'd like to detect if a file has changed since last commit, in order to open it and modify it.

I'm currently trying that:

```
def changes_between_two_diffs_grep(grepval):
    return run("git diff --name-only %s %s > /dev/null | grep '%s'; echo $?" % (env.point, env.old_point, grepval))

if (changes_between_two_diffs_grep('parameters.yml.dist') == "0"):
    edit_config()
```

But in vain.

Did I missed something?

Comment: Define in vain :) What's not working?

Comment: Why is this question tagged bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me you have mistakenly put the `> /dev/null` in the command.
It will cause nothing to pass (via pipe) to the `grep` command, hence nothing found by `grep`.

When `grep` finds nothing it returns 1.

This means you will forever get 1 from `changes_between_two_diffs_grep()`